# For a line how to find $y=mx+c$ if $x_1,y_1$ and $x_2,y_2$ in hand

Tags: geometry

How can I find $y=mx+c$ for a line? I have only two end points $x_1,y_1$ and $x_2,y_2$.

Comment: that are "endpoints" of a line-segment or points on a line?

Comment: x1,y1 and x2,y2 are end points

Comment: @VirenderSehwag If you found an answer helpful then you should upvote it, so that others can see that you found it helpful. You can also "[accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)" an answer if you feel that it answers your question sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy point-point formula for finding the equation of a line given only two points on the line.

First, recall that slope is "rise-over-run" and is given by  $$m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2-y_2}$$

Now, given slope, we can find the equation of the line using slope and one of two points: $(x_1, y_1)$. This is known as the point-slope form of an equation, and is given by $$y - y_1 = m(x-x_1).$$

Putting this altogether, given two points on the line $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$, we can form the equation for the line: $$y - y_1 = \left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\right)(x - x_1)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Replace one time $x$ by $x_1$ and $y$ by $y_1$ to get one equation, and then $x$ by $x_2$ and $y$ by $y_2$ to get a second equation. Then solve the system of two equations and two unknowns 
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} mx_1+c&=&y_1 \\ mx_2+c&=&y_2\end{array}\right.$$
to find $m$ and $c$. Then $y=mx+c$ is the line passing through $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. If you just want the line segment between these points restrict the domain to $x \in [\min\{x_1,x_2\},\max\{x_1,x_2\}]$.

Comment: this is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Solving equations is not necessarily easy, so in this answer I give an alternative method. However, both methods give you the same result (so long as you do them both correctly!).

The number $m$ is the *gradient* of the line. It can be found according to the following formula.
$$
m=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}
$$
Th number $c$ is the *$y$-intercept* of the line (that is, the line cuts the $y$-axis at the point $(0, c)$). To find $c$, you simply plug in one of your points into $y=mx+c$. For example, $y_1=mx_1+c$ so $c=y_1-mx_2$. Note that because $y_1$, $y_2$ and $m$ are all known numbers (because we found $m$, above), this gives you a number for $c$. Hence, you have your equation $y=mx+c$.